# How do I send emails through PHP to GMail?

Tags: php, email

I'm guessing that this:

```
<?php

    $emailTo = 'user1@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'I hope this works!';
    $body = 'Blah';
    $headers='From: user@gmail.com'

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

is not going to cut it. I searched for ways that I can send to email with SMTP auth and mail clients and programs such as PHPMailer, but I don't have a concise and direct answer yet thats helpful. Basically, I want a way to send emails to gmail, hotmail, etc (which will be my email) from another email (sender) through a form on my website

Questions:

1. Do I need to download a 3rd party library to this?
2. If not, how can I change the code above to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, just go for phpmailer or swiftmailer. `mail()` is mickey-mouse garbage and should only be used for simple/local stuff.

Comment: @MarcB True.. Unfortunately, im new to PHP and im having difficulties using the library..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use PHPMailer library.It is better than use mail native function because in PHPMailer you can use user authentication to avoid to send the email to spam.You can use this library without to configure a mail server. You can download in this link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

See an example:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // SMTP port
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // password

$mail->SetFrom('user@gmail.com', 'Test');

$mail->Subject    = "I hope this works!";

$mail->MsgHTML('Blah');

$address = "test@test.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Test");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify:
SetFrom is the sender and AddReplyTo would be me, the receiver, yes?
Also, can AddReplyTo equal a gmail address as well?

Comment: In this case, you dont need addReplyTo, SetFrom is the sender. The receiver is the $mail->AddAddress.

Comment: I see. Thanks! one more thing:
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com";
by yourdomain do you mean the websites domain or the mail domain that ur using for that case?

Comment: In this case you use the gmail domain:smtp.gmail.com.The phpmailer needs this information to identify the host the email is authenticanting the receiver.This is important to know if the its a true email.It s a techinque to avoid to send spams.

Comment: OK, great! Thanks for helping!