# How to send email in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I tried to send email using the mail() function of php. But it is not sending emails.

Code:

```
mail("boidurja@consultbop.com", "test", "testing");
```

These are my email configurations

SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
Encryption: SSL
Port: 465

When I send a test mail, I receive the email. But I don't receive any emails from the code I have written.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get any errors, possibly in the logs?

Comment: I think this is the error from error.log `sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install sendmail` ?

Comment: I am using a staging server. How do I run `sudo apt-get install sendmail`?

Comment: Can you ssh to that staging server? You need cli access to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send emails through PHP to GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777444/how-do-i-send-emails-through-php-to-gmail)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I send emails in prestashop:

```
$email = 'my.email@gmail.com;other.email@gmail.com';
//$email = 'my.email@gmail.com';
// Send Mail
$sendorders = Mail::Send($this->context->language->id,
'template_en',
'Order '.$id_order ,
    array(
                        '{order_id}'            => $id_order,
                        '{firstname}'           => $client_firstname,
                        '{lastname}'            => $client_lastname,
                        '{delivery_block_txt}'  => $delivery,
                        '{delivery_block_html}' => $delivery,
                        '{client_city}'         => $client_city,
                        '{client_postcode}'     => $client_postcode,
                        '{client_country}'      => $client_country,
                        '{client_phone}'        => $client_phone,
                        '{products_html}'       => $products_email,
    ),
    explode(';', $email),
    //$email,
    NULL, //receiver name
    'local@ps-test.com', //from email address
    'TEST Local Orders',  //from name
    $attach, //file attachment - no attachment = NULL
    NULL, //mode smtp

    _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'module_exemple/mails'

);
```

You can look at the documentation here: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/mail/

The variables within the array, we use them in the email template.

Answer (score 0):

PHP **mail()** function will use the installed mailserver on the same server to send out emails (if any) and not external SMTP(s).

If you want to send e-mail "the Prestashop way" you have a look at the Mail class

```
/classes/Mail.php
```

especially the **Send** method, that is the one that actually will send on the mail.

Note that you will need a template TPL with your mail content, you can check out default modules (like **ps_emailalerts**) to see how the code works.